# Calendar and timezones. Error

Tags: java, android, calendar, timezone, timezone-offset

Calendar gives the different values with the same data.
That is,

```
calT.setTimeZone(_.calc.ap.getTZ());
calT.setTimeInMillis(_.calc.ap.getCalMainTime());

calT.setTimeZone(timezonebase);
calT.setTimeInMillis(curData.getTimeBase());
```

In different part of code gives the different values.

`_.calc.ap.getTZ()` and timezonebase are the same and they are equal to `"Europe/Moscow"`
Time in millis for `_.calc.ap.getCalMainTime()` and `curData.getTimeBase()` is the same and equals to `568026000000L` (`1 Jan 1988 12:00 GMT+03:00`)

The result are different by one hour: (`1 Jan 1988 12:00 GMT+03:00`) or (`1 Jan 1988 13:00 GMT+03:00`

I think this bug coursed by Russia removed DST two years ago. But how fix this bug?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found one ugly solution. May be somebody found better. Reinitialize the calendar.

> calT = Calendar.getInstance();
>
> calT.setTimeZone(*.calc.ap.getTZ());
>   calT.setTimeInMillis(*.calc.ap.getCalMainTime());
>
> calT = Calendar.getInstance();
>
> calT.setTimeZone(timezonebase);
>   calT.setTimeInMillis(curData.getTimeBase());